# How to search LIKE "FIRSTLAST" but find "FIRST LAST"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have `...FROM clogin WHERE namer LIKE ?` that searches for a full name. However, there is a space in between the first and last name, resulting in it only finding results that are exact.

Is there a way to get names like the full name with just a first name without splitting the two up?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with mysqli, by the way. Mysql is the database you're using.

Comment: For comparing purpose you can concatinate the firstname and lastname from the database table as well as in your search string in the query

Comment: You can use RLIKE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp : namer RLIKE "FIRST\s*LAST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get names like the full name with just a first name without splitting the two up?

Nope, if you stick with LIKE.
You can use [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) though

Comment: How would I use fulltext search with params though? For instance, if I wanted to use wildcard %?

Comment: Oh, you have to duplicate the param and include the wildcard there like $login = "%$login%"; Thanks!